# Can i run an exe from the outlook taskbar

Tags: python, outlook, com, exe, outlook-web-addins

I am saving my emails on a strutured way in a structure of folders, depending on the email content.

For Example, if an email contains the tag "project123" i save this email in the project folder subfolder 123...

herefor i made a python application,
This application works with the win32com & tkinter.
It looking for the tags and proposes a folder + name. ( it also can open the local file explorer, save config file ..., it runs locally).

In outlook i added a macro on a button,
This macro activates the python application and the python application opens a tkinter window with the proposal where to save this email.

Nowdays some collegues want alo to use this.

I am looking to roll this out to multiple people.

- I made an executable of the python script, so they can run the code whitout python installed.
- I am looking for a button in the outlook ribbon to activate this exe file.

First i was looking to write a general plugin ( need an xml), but if i read correct this xml can only run web based, a javascript, it is not possible to go this way?
Second option was for me to work with a COM -plugin, but if i want to add the exe file as plugin, it executes the program, and not add this plugin... So i'm confused

Now the general question :
Is there a way to start an executable with a button from on the taskbar?

Our should i look for another way of working?

I prefer not to work with a macro, for an easy rollout...

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

COM addin would be the easiest way. If you write it in C#, you can use any Windows API, so you can launch any Windows executable. But then I am not sure why you'd want to use Python for that instead of doing everything in C#.

Comment: The main reason is because i am familar with python... maybe i should consider re-write the application.

Comment: If you decide to rewrite, consider re-writing this in JavaScript, then you can have this as an Outlook Web Add-in that can look at the message and provide UI to "accept the folder suggestion" and move the item using add-in JS APIs. And this would be a cross-platform approach as a nice bonus. Plus, you can then publish it to add-ins store if you want.